# Unicode Substitutions using Regex , Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a string as follows:

```
str1 = "heylisten\uff08there is something\uff09to say \uffa9"
```

I need to replace the unicode values detected by my regex expression with spaces on either sides.

**Desired output string:**

```
out = "heylisten \uff08 there is something \uff09 to say  \uffa9 "
```

I have used an re.findall to get all the matches and then replace them. It looks like:

```
p1 = re.findall(r'\uff[0-9a-e][0-9]', str1, flags = re.U)  
out = str1
for item in p1:
    print item
    print out
    out= re.sub(item, r" " + item + r" ", out)
```

**And this outputs:**

```
'heylisten\\ uff08 there is something\\ uff09 to say \\ uffa9 '
```

What is wrong with the above that it prints an extra "\" and also separates it from `uff`? I even tried with `re.search` but it seems to only separate `\uff08`. Is there a better way?

Comment: But it doesn't seems you replaced any thing ? !!

Comment: I didn't get you . I want spaces on either sides on each match. But the \ seem to separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a string as follows:
>
> ```
> str1 = "heylisten\uff08there is something\uff09to say \uffa9"
> ```
>
> I need to replace the unicode values ...

You don't *have* any unicode values. You have a bytestring.

```
str1 = u"heylisten\uff08there is something\uff09to say \uffa9"
 ...
p1 = re.sub(ur'([\uff00-\uffe9])', r' \1 ', str1)
```

Comment: it isn't working.. outputs 'heylisten\\uff08there is something\\uff09to say \\uffa9'

Comment: yeah i read it and I guess I framed the example wrong..  it works with the u outside..

Answer (score 1):

```
print re.sub(r"(\\uff[0-9a-e][0-9])", r" \1 ", x)
```

You can directly use this `re.sub`. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/67

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\\uff[0-9a-e][0-9])', re.UNICODE)
test_str = u"heylisten\uff08there is something\uff09to say \uffa9"
subst = u" \1 "

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Output:

> ```
> heylisten \uff08 there is something \uff09 to say  \uffa9
> ```

Comment: your import re code ouputs this : u'heylisten\uff08there is something\uff09to say \uffa9'

Comment: @Swordy directly use `print re.sub(r"(\\uff[0-9a-e][0-9])", r" \1 ", x)` x is uur string.